# Saving byte array with very small values

Tags: c++, arrays

If I have two numbers, lets say 4 and 2, that I want to save to a file. Both are of type `int` so they should occupy 4 bytes each.

But isn't it a waste of space since the numbers are so small and they could be represented with just 2 and 4 bits?

Is there any technique that helps you possibly pack more numbers int the same space?

Comment: `int` is more typically 4 bytes on modern systems, not 2.

Comment: Yes, that's called bit packing. You can do it as long as you know that all of your numbers will be of a certain size.

Comment: If you wished to take it to the extreme (without employing compression), you could actually save these two numbers using 7 bits (**EDIT:** 5 bits). However, given that ~1,000,000,000 bytes of Flash Memory costs $1, do you really think it's worth it?

Comment: @enhzflep: 7? Why not 5?

Comment: @Matt - 4 is 100b and 2 is 10b - so I was in error, you can do it using 5 bits.

Comment: Well its not so much for the practicality of it as for simple curiosity. Because wasting so many bits just to save the number 2 for example made me wonder if there is a better way. Matt id suppose the more interesting case would be when my numbers are not of the same size. If it is even possible that is.

Comment: @dearn44: That is possible, but only worth it with large numbers. A byte is a really small amount of memory. You can look into how [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encodes integers from 0 to 1114111 depending on size in 1-4 bytes.

Comment: @dearn44 - well in that case, yes, certainly you can. There are all kinds of pitfalls, gotchas and performance penalties to be aware of though. (Tom Carpenter discusses a few worth considering) On a modern cpu with modern quantities of memory, this will rarely, if ever be a useful exercise. _However_, if programming on micro-controllers with very limited RAM, it may be a better use of program-memory and cpu cycles to pack your data like you ask. Also, 8bit (video-game) consoles (Nintendo SNES, Sega MS, etc) needed to pull tricks like this. :)

Comment: @Matt - :grins: - it seems we each made an error of calculation initially. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do that using bit fields, which will allow you to create more tightly packed data.
For example:

```
typedef struct {
   unsigned int first:3;
   unsigned int second:3;
   unsigned int third:3; //and so on
} PackedData;
...
PackedData a;
a.first = 4;
a.second = 2;
```

That would create a data type with three 3bit numbers. You could extend it to enough to fill up the int.

The trouble with this is two fold:

1. You have to overhead of accessing the bitfields - lots of shift and
   bitmask operations.
2. You can't access the data in any sort of array format. Pointers to bitfield entries are not possible.

---

**Additional Info:**

To write the above structure to a file, you can simply typecast the PackedData variable to an (unsigned) int type, and then save that to a file. When you want to read it, you do the read as an (unsigned) int, and then typecast back to PackedData.

A word of caution though, this only works if the systems saving and reading the data both use the same endianness. Otherwise the data will get reversed.

---

One other point on your question, if you have the number 4, you need at least 3 bits to store your data.

Comment: @Matt If you only wish to store 4 and 2, then you could use one bit. But if you want to store say 0 as well, then you couldn't store the number 4 in 2bits.

Comment: Sorry I had a brain fart and forgot that 4 is three bits in ordinary binary.

Comment: You are of curse right on your last comment. That should teach me to not be in such a hurry when writing. Actually your solution could be useful. Because what I had in mind was a very big sequence of very small numbers. So I could use a greedy way of determining of what type a number must be and the saving them to file.

Answer (score -2):

1. int occupy 4 byte
2. if you need 2 byte unsigned integer then use WORD (uint16_t)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, it was not so much as to what I should use in order to save those numbers, but more on if there could be a way to pack them in the same space.

Comment: not, for example, you have 2 numbers 1 and 2
(0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001)
(0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010)

you pack them on 2 bytes

(0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0010)

How do I know this 2 numbers 1 and 2 or the number 65538 ???

Comment: Thats the hard part. Or else I could just put them side by side in a very long stream. There must be a way of later getting back your original numbers.

Comment: how do you know how many numbers with the stream??? 1 or 2? You then have to keep another variable indicates the number of stored variables. ie This makes no sense.

Comment: I know it does not, yet something useful came out of it. Tom's answer taught  me, and hopefully others something new.

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect. C++ inherits rules pertaining to integer sizes from C. C merely states, that an `int` is at least 16 bits.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you could try `short`? `short` only takes one byte from memory instead of two.

In your program, you could use an `if` to decide which form you want to write to the file.

```
if (aNumber > SHRT_MAX || aNumber < SHRT_MIN) write(aNumber);
else write((short)aNumber);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: No, short takes at least two bytes. char takes only one byte.

Comment: Hi Wind, its not that I actually worry on how much those to numbers will occupy. I was just wondering why should I waste so many bits for such small numbers.

Comment: Alright, I understood this in a wrong way. But only when you have a lot of small numbers, you want to pack them.